# Call atribute of class object in class function

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, class, integration

```
class client:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = str(input("Name: "))
        self.surname = str(input("Surname: "))
        self.year = str(input("Year of birth: "))
        self.id =(self.name[0] + self.surname[0] + self.year)
        self.balance = 0
    def Transfer(self):
        balance = self.balance
        action = int(input("How much would you like to transfer ?"))
        if action > balance:
            print("Not enough money")
        else:
            id = str(input("choose user you want to send money to:"))
            self.balance = balance - action
            #call id of crated client here to choose him as reciever of transfer
            print(f"Succesfully transfered {action}$, your balance right now is {self.balance}$ have a nice day !!")
    def Balance(self):
        print(f"Your account balance is: {self.balance}")
```

Task : Send money between users
Problem : i have no idea how to call specific ID of class object that will be                           created

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. I can't understand the question. Please try to write in complete, clear, short sentences. Explain what the existing code does, and show code to *set up the situation* where you are stuck

Comment: hello @KarlKnechtel thank you for noticing my question, in my code user ID is created from first name of name and surname as well as year of birth, that id is created automatically once you put your informations, thanks to that you will have your login ID as well as ID which can be put to make money transfer but as you can see in code i posted
id = str(input("choose user you want to send money to:"))
i have no idea how to call for id of class i can send you whole code if necessary

Comment: Do not try to "send" anything (there is no DM functionality here anyway). Instead, [edit] the question to clarify the question and add missing information.

Comment: understood, i made some changes to the question